# Flutter/Dart DateFormat 12:27 to 00:27 bug, hour 0 bug

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with Dart intl package while using DateFormat:

`formatDateTime(DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").parse(fortune.readFinishedAt ?? "2025-12-27 12:27:45"))`

When I use this code, I want to take 12:27 for the hour part but DateFormat gives 00:27 to me.
hour property is `0`.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I want to use 24 hour format. only 12:00-59 it gives zero :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to the 24 hour format use this `DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")`.

Answer (score 0):

use formate like I mention below:-

```
formatDateTime(DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a").parse(fortune.readFinishedAt ?? "2025-12-27 12:27:45")),
```

use hh:mm a it will gave you time in am/pm formate

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to use 12 hr time period

use formate like I mention below:-
if yopu want to use 12 hr time
use (hh:mm) a insted of (hh:mm)it will gave you time in am/pm formate

```
formatDateTime(DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a").parse(fortune.readFinishedAt ?? "2025-12-27 12:27:45"))
```

Comment: I want to use 24 hour format. only 12:00-59 it gives zero :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
formatDateTime(DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss").parse(fortune.readFinishedAt ?? "2025-12-27 12:27:45")),
```

For more info : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Comment: I want to use 24 hour format. only 12:00-59 it gives zero :)

Comment: Use This  : formatDateTime(DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss").parse(fortune.readFinishedAt ?? "2025-12-27 12:27:45")),